Pop!_OS 22.04 "404 Not Found [IP: 108.157.60.76 80]" error while updating in terminal
When I try to do sudo apt update in pop os I get error regarding to public key. Here is the complete output:
Hit:1 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                            
Ign:2 https://releases.warp.dev/linux/deb stable InRelease                                                                      
Hit:3 https://releases.warp.dev/linux/deb stable Release                                                       
Hit:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                   
Err:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
Hit:6 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary jammy InRelease
Hit:7 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy InRelease
Get:8 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Hit:9 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                     
Hit:10 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                     
Hit:11 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                   
Ign:12 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                      
Ign:13 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 48x48 Icons                                                         
Ign:14 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                         
Ign:15 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons                                                       
Ign:16 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 128x128 Icons                                                       
Ign:12 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                      
Ign:13 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 48x48 Icons                                                         
Ign:14 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                         
Ign:15 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons                                                       
Ign:16 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 128x128 Icons                                                       
Ign:12 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                      
Ign:13 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 48x48 Icons                                                         
Ign:14 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                         
Ign:15 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons                                                       
Ign:16 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 128x128 Icons                                                       
Ign:12 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                      
Err:13 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 48x48 Icons                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 108.157.60.76 80]
Ign:14 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                         
Ign:15 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons                                                       
Ign:16 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted DEP-11 128x128 Icons                                                       
Ign:12 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                      
Fetched 270 kB in 23s (11.7 kB/s)                                                                                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
W: Failed to fetch https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
E: Failed to fetch http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar  404  Not Found [IP: 108.157.60.76 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


When I want to see /etc/apt/sources.list file the output says:
This file is deprecated in Pop!_OS.
See `man deb822` and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/system.sources.


And the output of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/system.sources file is
X-Repolib-Name: Pop_OS System Sources
Enabled: yes
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu/
Suites: jammy jammy-security jammy-updates jammy-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
X-Repolib-Default-Mirror: http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu
X-Repolib-ID: system

I can provide additional informations if you like. Cheers
